# query 2 tables with exact column names and types

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables with identical column names and types, I would like to query all of the content from both tables into one result set, of just one set of column names. So tbl1.ID and tbl2.ID should be in one col.ID as tbl1.data and tbl2.data should be in one col.data. There are no common values between the tables, records are unrelated so nothing to JOIN on.

I am using vb.net to query an Access DB and update a SQL DB.

I believe in SQL I can use a SELECT INTO but I am not sure how to do this in access with one query, or do I need to create a table and just push everything into it first.

thanks,

Comment: In SQL Server, you can use UNION ALL.   I don't know if it's available in Access.

Comment: in Access create a union query, open that query in SQL view and use that code in your VB application.

Comment: @Jeroen Post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access you can create a "Union Query". How this is done exactly depends on the version of Access you are using. Open that query in "SQL View" and then use the code from there in your VB application.